# использование Time.current на Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails

После того как выложил проект на Travis CI не прошло два теста, после нескольких часов поиска дошел до того что не срабатывает функция Time.current. Возможно необходимо подключить что то или настроить часовые пояса на удалленой машине. 
Заранее спасибо

Comment: В смысле, не срабатывает? Что при попытке её вызова происходит?

Comment: Если не сложно разместите в вопросе сообщение об ошибке? Если у вас ActiveSupport не подключен, у вас много чего не должно работать.

Comment: какой руби вы используете на travis ci? Если приложение рельсовое, то для получение времени текущего нужно использовать `Time.zone.now`

Comment: Спасибо, Time.zone.now сработало!